# 2x2 subfigures with tikz graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, subcaption

I saw that this has been asked before, but none of the solutions appear to work in my document. I am trying to set an 2x2 grid of sub figures, each filled with a tikz graph. However, no matter how much i adjust the textwidth or the scale, they are always displayed one below the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Ex2]%
{{\small Ex1}}    
\end{subfigure}

\quad

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}  
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]%
{{\small Ex2}}    
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip 

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}   
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]%
{{\small Ex3}}
\end{subfigure}

\quad

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}   
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]%
{{\small Ex4}}    
\end{subfigure}
\caption[ Ex ]
{\small A small Ex} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming you are using `subcaption` (a full MWE would be helpful), you need to remove the empty lines between the subfigures. Each will appear in a separate row if you have blank lines between them.

Comment: Thank you... I am a Latex beginner writing my thesis, and I was not aware of the spacing requirement. You can post it as an answer if you would like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subcaption` package interprets spaces between `subfigure` environments within the `figure` to be new rows. Removing the space between these environments (and the unnecessary `\quad` and `bigskip`) yields the desired 2x2

[image: two rows figures]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Ex2]%
{{\small Ex1}}    
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}  
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]%
{{\small Ex2}}    
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}   
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]%
{{\small Ex3}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}   
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\node[circle,draw]{$x$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]%
{{\small Ex4}}    
\end{subfigure}
\caption[ Ex ]
{\small A small Ex} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: I agree. Added.